# streaming an speex encoded ogg file via udpsrc

Tags: gstreamer

Currently i'm working on ubuntu 14.02 LTS.
I installed gstreamer following the steps found on the following page :
http://blog.nicolargo.com/2010/05/installation-de-tout-les-composants-gstreamer-sous-ubuntu.html

I'm working trying to stream an file which was created with the command line:

```
arecord -d 5 -f s16_le -r 8000 | speexenc - /media/ram/test.spx
```

I've played the file test.spx with the following command line and verified the recorded audio :

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/media/ram/test.spx ! oggdemux ! speexdec ! alsasink
```

But, i need to stream the file over the network (filesrc -> udpsrc) so I'm using the following commands.
On host:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/media/ram/test.spx ! oggdemux ! speexdec ! udpsink host=<target@> port=8888
```

On target:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=8888 ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false
```

but nothing is received and i have no idea what is wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using RTP in the way?
Although I think it should be working without RTP.. but I dont know how (I remember I used mpegtsmux maybe..

This one was tested with arecord etc and its working..

Transmitting side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="./test.spx" ! oggdemux ! rtpspeexpay ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8888
```

Receiving side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8888 caps="application/x-rtp" ! queue ! rtpspeexdepay ! speexdec ! alsasink
```

Ispired by [this link](http://labs.isee.biz/index.php/Example_GStreamer_Pipelines#Network_Streaming)

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your answer, it do works and yes i dont mind using RTP. I'll mark it as solved. I'm really a beginner with gstreamer and i wasn't using the correct filters sequence. Your example helped me a lot